# Why does Decimal.TryParse return false when converting a number retrieved from a web page?

Tags: c#, decimal, html-agility-pack

I am using the HtmlAgilityPack to retrieve information from various websites as below. `fhfaRate = "3.62"` in debug, but `isNum` is `false` and `myRate = 0.0`.
It I type `"3.62"` into the `TryParse`, that works fine, but if I copy the value from `fhfaRate` (in debug) and paste into the `TryParse`, that returns `false` as well despite looking like this - `"3.62"`.

It's like `"3.62" <> "3.62"` and I'm stumped.

```
doc = web.Load(fhfaUrl);
string fhfaRate = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//td[@class='tg-s6z2  ms-rteTableEvenCol-4']/p").InnerText;
decimal myRate;
bool isNum = Decimal.TryParse(fhfaRate, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out myRate);
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint on that line, and when the breakpoint hints, take a look at `fhfaRate.ToCharArray()` in the Watch window. There may be an invisible character in there. Also examine the value of `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`.

Comment: Does it really just contain the chars for "3.62" or does the char array contain more?

Comment: Or try decoding string on debugging `string.Join(" ", fhfaRate.Select(c => ((int)c).ToString("x4")))` the outcome should be `"0033 002e 0036 0032"` (for `"3.62"`)

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! There was a fifth character hiding in there, 8203, zero width space. I used substring to catch the first 4 characters, but maybe there is a better way?

Comment: @Doug, update the question with your latest findings so that people can answer it without reading all the comments ;)  If no one will answer, you may post your own answer later on.

Comment: @Doug Can you edit your answer out of the question and add that into an answer of your own, you can also accept your own answer

Comment: The best thing you can do is to find out why the white space is there at all, maybe you can avoid it just by placing the whole HTML element on the same line. Second best is, to use `string.Trim()` to remove white spaces.

Comment: Nothing much I can do about it, because I'm scraping it off the web page. String.Trim didn't work because it's not really a white space.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to those who helped. It turns out that there was a zero width space (8203) appended in the `CharArray` for the string. I used a sub string for the first 4 characters and voila, I have a decimal value.

I got to thinking after I did that - if the value went to 2 digits it would break, so I looked around and found this instead.

```
InnerText.Replace((char)0x200B, ' ');
```

Comment: The zero space character is really mean. The trim function also accepts an array of characters, so you could use it like this: `InnerText.Trim(new char[] { '\x2009', '\x200B' })`